# Ansible - need to output all the hosts in the playbook into a configuration file

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I'll try to make this brief... I'm setting up ansible to write a PostgreSQL pg_hba.conf file, and what I want to do is permit any db server to replicate to any other db server. This way I don't have to reconfigure in the event of a failure. I want ansible to insert lines for each host listed in the group "db". These entries must be CIDR types. So, far I've only succeeded in getting each system to show their own CIDR in the file. I've looked extensively with no joy, but here's what I'm trying to use:

```
- name: Update the pg_hba.conf file
  lineinfile:
    path: '{{ pg_data  }}/{{ pg_cluster_name }}/pg_hba.conf'
    regexp: 'hostssl replication'
    insertafter: 'hostssl   replication'
    line: "hostssl replication      rplctn_usr  {{ hostvars[ '{{ item }}' ]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}/32     md5"
    with_items: groups['db']
  tags:
    - "pg_hba.conf"
```

Nothing I've done gets the {{ item }} variable to expand properly. Anyone?

Comment: Have you tried : `line: "hostssl replication      rplctn_usr  {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}/32     md5"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to reference the var to iterate through with braces:

```
with_items: "{{ groups['db'] }}"
```

Second, `item` is the var representing the value of each iteration. Inside `{{ }}` you can reference any vars directly without extra braces:

```
{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, After several false starts due to incorrect pages on the internet, I made this work this morning. My syntax is exactly what you wrote, even though I came up with it prior to reading your post.

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer here even if you have found it by yourself :) Could be useful for people looking for the same thing.